# How do I associate an Activerecord Object with Em-Websocket connection?

Tags: ruby, activerecord, sinatra, em-websocket

I am new to ruby. I am trying to implement a chat client using em-websocket. I have the following code:

```
  EventMachine::WebSocket.start(host: '0.0.0.0', port: 8080) do |websock|
    websock.onopen do
      puts 'New Connection Opened'
      cookies = CGI::Cookie::parse( websock.request["cookie"])
      person = Person.where(['token = ?', cookies["token"]]).first
      unless person       
        websock.close(code = nil, body = {Error: "Invalid Token"}.to_json)  unless person
        return
      end
      puts "#{person.name} authenticated!"
      person=person.attributes.merge(websock.attributes) # this doesn't work
      # Subscribe the new user to the GrindServer.realtime_channel with the callback function for the push action
      new_user = GrindServer.realtime_channel.subscribe { |msg| websock.send msg }
      GrindServer.online_people << person
      # Add the new user to the user list
      @users[websock.object_id] = new_user

      # Push the last messages to the user
      # message.all.each do |message|
        # websock.send message.to_json
      # end
      # puts GrindServer.realtime_channel.inspect
      # Broadcast the notification to all users
      onlinepeople = []
      GrindServer.online_people.each do |onli|
        onlinepeople << person
      end

      # Send last 10 messages to the newly connected user
      websock.send Message.where({ receiver_id: [0, person.id}).last(10).to_json

      GrindServer.realtime_channel.push ({
        'id' => 0,
        'sender_id' => 0,
        'messagetext' => "#{person.name} joined. <$<^<#<#{@users.length}>#>^>$> users in chat",
        'users' => onlinepeople,
        'metadata' => websock.request["query"]["id"],
        }.to_json)
    end
  ...# other event handlers
  end
```

Basically I am trying to maintain a list of Person (ActiveRecord Object) and its corresponding WebSocket::Connection Object.

[Server code](https://bitbucket.org/AEonAX/grind/src/ec91c9525b37d6e7a4bc30ef9230ab6dd1161a24/GrindServer/app.rb?at=master#cl-348)

[Migration](https://bitbucket.org/AEonAX/grind/src/ec91c9525b37d6e7a4bc30ef9230ab6dd1161a24/GrindServer/db/migrate/20150131130010_create_tasks_people_documents_unreads_and_comments.rb?at=master)

Update: Even if I am unable to merge. I should be able to just attach a note to websocket that this belongs to a person named "x"?

Comment: If any more information is required / suggestions to improve the question Please comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by using a hash.

```
  EventMachine::WebSocket.start(host: '0.0.0.0', port: 8080) do |websock|
    websock.onopen do
      puts 'New Connection Opened'
      cookies = CGI::Cookie::parse( websock.request["cookie"])
      person = Person.where(['token = ?', cookies["token"]]).first
      unless person       
        websock.close(code = nil, body = {Error: "Invalid Token"}.to_json)  unless person
        return
      end
      puts "#{person.name} authenticated!"
      # person=person.attributes.merge(websock.attributes)
      # Subscribe the new user to the GrindServer.realtime_channel with the callback function for the push action
      new_user = GrindServer.realtime_channel.subscribe { |msg| websock.send msg }
      GrindServer.online_people << {:ws_oid => websock.object_id,
                                    :websocket => websock, 
                                    :person_name => person.name,
                                    :person_trigram => person.trigram} # this solves it
      # Add the new user to the user list
      @users[websock.object_id] = new_user

      onlinepeople = []
      GrindServer.online_people.each do |onli|
        onlinepeople << onli.except(:websocket)
      end

      # Send last 10 messages to the newly connected user
      websock.send Message.where({ receiver_id: [0, person.id]}).last(10).to_json

      GrindServer.realtime_channel.push ({
        'id' => 0,
        'sender_id' => 0,
        'messagetext' => "#{person.name} joined. <$<^<#<#{@users.length}>#>^>$> users in chat",
        'users' => onlinepeople,
        'metadata' => person.trigram,
        }.to_json)
    end
```

Comment: Just a thought: you can run websockets inside your Rails app by using the [Plezi framework](https://github.com/boazsegev/plezi) (Plezi allows you to use both frameworks at the same time, but requires that allow it to set the Rack server to [GRHttp server](https://github.com/boazsegev/GRHttp) ). This way you can use your Rails model's code inside your Plezi Websocket controller.